# Angular Material Nav Sidebar only shows on responsive resizing

Tags: html, css, node.js, angular, angular-material

I'm following this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6qhzG7mObU) tutorial on how to set-up Angular Material Sidenav with the toolbar, but it only seems to take effect as soon as I resize my page. I do not know if it is a glitch on my side, or if I missed something minor.

[Doesn't show the menu icon on page load (even if page starts on mobile size)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj2M0.png)

[Shows menu icon as soon as page resizes to a mobile size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqh4n.png)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, share } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-bar',
  templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-bar.component.css']
})
export class NavBarComponent {

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      share()
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>ProjectVAS</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

.sidenav-container {
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidenav {
  width: 150px;
}
```

It must just show the menu button (or side on page load irrespective)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with tutorials sometimes is that they tell you what to do but not what exactly it is that you are doing. Since apparently you are new to Angular Material, you should take some time to read the docs and understand the code you are using: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview.

The `mode` property controls the appearance of the sidenav. The `opened` property controls whether or not it is open/showing. You've 'bound' both of those properties to the breakpoint observer so that their values change depending on - in this case - whether or not the device is a handset. As a result - if you change your screen size, the behavior of the menu may change.

Fix it by setting the properties statically:

```
mode="side"
opened="true"
```

Or whatever behavior you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was able to do what I wanted to do. All I had to do was remove the *ngIf="isHandset$ | async" from the button tag.